# Delay jQuery fadeIn 5 seconds

Tags: jquery

How can I properly delay this fade in by 5 seconds? When I change the number '(2000)' it loads the image from opaque to transparent. I want to simply delay the fade in by 5 seconds altogether.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#page_effect').fadeIn(2000);
});

<div id="page_effect" style="display:none;">
```

Update

```
<!--1.0 Fader-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#page_effect').delay( 5000 ).fadeIn(2000);

});
</script>
```

Comment: [`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/), [`setTimeout`](http://mdn.io/settimeout)…

Comment: Thanks a bunch @nietonfir . Worked perfectly. Feel free to post your answer so I can accept it if you want!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways how you can achieve your desired solution. I will post two that come immediately to mind.

First would be jQuery's own [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/):

```
$('#page_effect').delay(5000).fadeIn(2000);
```

The second one is obviously [`setTimeout`](http://mdn.io/settimeout):

```
var effectTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    $('#page_effect').fadeIn(2000);
}, 5000);
```

Storing the timer lets you cancel it if necessary/required.

A third - and in my opinion the preferred - solution would be via [CSS](http://mdn.io/transition):

```
#page_effect {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out 5s;
}
#page_effect.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

You than simply add the class at domReady. And instead of defining the delay in the transition, you could use `setTimeout` again (but don't forget to remove the delay from the CSS declaration).